# What's correct syntax to SELECT statement in YQL results?

Tags: xml, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-boss-api

I'm using `boss.search` table to extract the data in XML, but I would like to retrieve specific fields.

The standard syntax is:

```
SELECT * from boss.search WHERE q="stackoverflow" AND ck = 'ConsumerKey' AND secret = 'ConsumerSecret';
```

which works.

But when I'm trying to select fields like `"/title"` or `"/results/result/title"`, I've got the syntax error:

> Query syntax error(s) [line 1:7 expecting fields_or_star got '/result/title']

What's the correct syntax of retrieving fields (such as `title`)?

The REST response looks like:

```
<results>
    <bossresponse>
        <web>
            <results>
                <result>
                    <date/>
                    <clickurl>https://example.com/</clickurl>
                    <url>https://example.com/</url>
                    <dispurl type="default">https://example.com/</dispurl>
                    <title type="default">Example</title>
                    <abstract type="default">Example</abstract>
                </result>
                <result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that at '[Syntax of SELECT - Specifying the Elements Returned](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/select_statement.html)' ([cached](http://web.archive.org/web/20150102200912/https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/projection.html)) Yahoo Query Language documentation.

If the fields in the result set contain sub-fields, you can indicate the sub-fields by using periods (dots) as delimiters.

**Custom tables**

For example, for the `social.profile` table, to get only the `imageUrl` sub-field of the `image` field from the following example:

```
. . .
<results>
    <profile xmlns="http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng">
        <image>
            <imageUrl>http://l.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/identity/nopic_192.gif</imageUrl>
        </image>
    </profile>
</results>
```

enter the following:

```
select image.imageUrl from social.profile where guid=me
```

**BOSS API**

In BOSS response it's a bit different. To get *title* from boss.search table, you need to name the field as: `web.results.result.title`, e.g.

```
SELECT web.results.result.title FROM boss.search WHERE q="stackoverflow"
```

**HTML**

To get just the content from an HTML page, you can specify `content` keyword after the word `SELECT`. A statement with the `content` keyword processes the HTML in the following order:

1. It looks for any element named `content` within the elements found.
2. If an element named `content` is not found, the statement looks for an attribute named `content`.
3. If neither an element nor attribute named `content` is found, the statement returns the element's `textContent`.

For example, the following statement extracts only the HTML links (`href` tags) for *Yahoo Groups*:

```
SELECT href FROM html WHERE url="http://groups.yahoo.com/search?query=surfing&sort=relevance" and compat="html5" AND xpath='//li[contains(@class,"hbox groupsSearch-result-entry")]/h4/a'
```

The following statement, for example, returns the textContent of each anchor `a` tag retrieved by the *XPath* expression:

```
SELECT content FROM html WHERE url="http://groups.yahoo.com/search?query=surfing&sort=relevance" AND compat="html5" AND xpath='//li[contains(@class,"hbox groupsSearch-result-entry")]/h4/a'
```

Source: [Extracting HTML - Using YQL and Open Data Tables](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html#html_table-select_content) at YQL Guide